# Symfony2 empty BBDD on edit form

Tags: php, database, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this forms + controllers http://pastebin.com/wLPyXvbj

They are working when I'm adding data to DB (new data) but I have troubles while editing, I explain here the best I can.

- Case 1

I edit EVERY SINGLE FIELD, data is updated on DB OK.

- Case 2

I try to edit FEW fields, only fields I want users to edit instead of editing everything. Fields that have been available for update are inserted into DB without problem, but the other fields, thoose which I didn't want users to modify instead of keeping the old values in DB (because they HAVEN'T changed), they all turn empty values.

So there is something wrong with "selective editing" instead of "all fields edit" but I can't find the problem... I can't make an all fields edit form because some of them are static, no edits.

This is the controller I'm using for the edit action, as you can see it is diferent from the `newAction`

```
 public function agentupdateAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $comments = new VtigerTicketcomments();
        $session = $this->get("session");
        $proyecto = $session->get('proyecto');
        $assets = $session->get('assets');
        $contacts = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.contactid, u.email, u.phone, u.mobile FROM WbsGoclientsBundle:VtigerContactdetails u')->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
        foreach($assets as $a)
            $uuids[$a['UUID']] = $a['UUID'];
        $entity = $em->getRepository('WbsGoclientsBundle:VtigerTicketcf')->find($id);
        $ticket = $entity->getId();
        $solution = $ticket->getSolution();

        $ticketcfForm   = $this->createForm(new TicketcfType($uuids, $session->get('contacts'), $session->get('rol'), $session->get('tecnicos')), $entity);
        $ticketcfForm->submit($request);
        if($ticketcfForm->isValid())
        {
            $data = $ticketcfForm->getData();
            if($ticket->getStatus() == 'Closed')
            {
                if(!$ticket->getSolution())
                    $ticket->setSolution($solution);
                $workflow = new ComVtigerWorkflowtaskQueue();
                $workflow->setTaskid('9');
                $workflow->setEntityid('9x'.$id);
                $workflow->setDoafter('0');
                $em->persist($workflow);
                $em->flush();

                $hoy = new \DateTime();
                if($ticketcf->getFReso() == null)
                    $ticketcf->setFReso($hoy->format('d-m-Y H:i:s'));
            }
            $em->persist($ticket);
            $em->flush();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('tickets_show', array('id' => $ticket->getTicketNo())));
        }

        return $this->render('WbsGoclientsBundle:Tickets:edit.html.twig', array(
                'entity'      => $entity,
                'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
                'rol'         => $session->get('rol'),
                'ticket_form' => $ticketForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to not respect the Symfony2 good practices ? these are describe here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html, here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/basic-mapping.html and here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html
As is, sorry but I cannot understand your code so can't help you.

Comment: plus: read some more about doctrine. I think you misunderstood the usage of persist and flush methods

Comment: Actually, methods used here are the one that Symfony2 generates when using `doctrine:generate:crud` command from console. 

Also, I've read symfony2 good practices but the way they tell us to use some things, isn't the way I need it to be used, like, for example, submitting in the same form 4 entities not at the sime time but in an specific order because they have relational `id` fields that needs to be created in A before B and before C or D.

Thank you anyway.